# fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/opc/xxx' in Oracle Cloud

Tags: linux, git

When I do `git log` in repository, Git always says

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/opc/xxx'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

git config --global --add safe.directory /home/opc/xxx
```

I'm using Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

What was I expecting: Show log successfully

I tried:

- `git config --global --add safe.directory /home/opc/xxx` - success, but not working
- `git config --global --add safe.directory *` - success, but not working
- `sudo chown -R opc /home/opc/xxx` - success, but not working
- `sudo chown -R opc /home/opc/xxx/.git` - success, but not working
- `sudo chmod g+w -R .git` - success, but not working
- Re-clone repository - same error